# How much computation should src_key_padding_mask reduce compared to no mask?

Tags: pytorch, transformer-model, inference, onnxruntime

I have trained two transformer models in PyTorch and I export them to ONNX where I am doing an inference session. The only difference is that when I export the ONNX model in which I wish to use the transformer's `src_key_padding_mask` input (in `.forward()`) , I specify it. Example:

#1 (no mask):
`torch.onnx.export(model.cpu(), X.view(1,MAXSEQLEN), "model.onnx", verbose=False, input_names=['model_inputs'], output_names=['model_outputs'])`

vs

#2 (with an additional mask input): `torch.onnx.export(model.cpu(), (X.view(1,MAXSEQLEN), X_pad_mask.view(1,MAXSEQLEN)), "model-with-padmask.onnx", verbose=False, input_names=['model_inputs', 'padding_mask'], output_names=['model_outputs'])`

The issue is that I am not seeing any difference in inference time between the two when I use the padding mask. I can run a test where I sweep the amount of padding in the input from almost full padding to no padding (and obviously use the appropriate mask, where True indicates a corresponding padding token). Expected behavior would be that as I am increasing the amount of padding/masking, inference will execute faster because more of the computation should be getting masked out.

Note when I try exporting I do get a warning--
`C:\Users\<user>\Miniconda3\envs\py10\lib\site-packages\torch\onnx\utils.py:620: UserWarning: ONNX Preprocess - Removing mutation from node aten::masked_fill_ on block input: 'src_key_padding_mask'. This changes graph semantics. (Triggered internally at ..\torch\csrc\jit\passes\onnx\remove_inplace_ops_for_onnx.cpp:355.) _C._jit_pass_onnx_remove_inplace_ops_for_onnx(graph, module)`
which I can't quite understand.

---

Additional info after more testing today...

I decided to compare three quantities. Sweep max sequence length, and observe the inference times under the following three conditions:

- (i) feeding both `x` and `x_mask` into the model with `x_mask` all False (ie. the mask input is there, but it is effectively no mask);
- (ii) feeding both `x` and `x_mask` into the model with `x_mask` half set to true (ie. mask the second half of `x` values); and
- (iii) ONLY feed `x` into the model (`src_padding_mask` = None).

In experiments (i) and (ii) inference latencies are roughly similar. In experiment (iii), latencies are roughly similar for smaller lengths, but start to become faster for sequences of larger length... I would have expected the converse to be true: when not using any padding mask, this would hurt latency especially at longer lengths...

Answer (score 0):

After looking deeper through the code, I believe I was mistaken that computation would be reduced. It seems like the mask is actually just used to ignore the pads in the softmax of the scaled dot product attention, not actually filter off the corresponding computations

```py
    # Efficient implementation equivalent to the following:
    scale_factor = 1 / math.sqrt(Q.size(-1)) if scale is None else scale
    attn_mask = torch.ones(L, S, dtype=torch.bool).tril(diagonal=0) if is_causal else attn_mask
    attn_mask = attn_mask.masked_fill(not attn_mask, -float('inf')) if attn_mask.dtype==torch.bool else attn_mask
    attn_weight = torch.softmax((Q @ K.transpose(-2, -1) * scale_factor) + attn_mask, dim=-1)
    attn_weight = torch.dropout(attn_weight, dropout_p)
    return attn_weight @ V
```